# How to set the NTP server in GNOME 3?

Tags: gnome, ntp

In Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop, the time and date settings are managed in the Settings app, under the "Date & Time" category. You can set the time zone, time format, manually set the time, or turn on automatic time sync.

Unfortunately, what's missing is the option to set the NTP server used for automatic time sync. What is the proper way to do that?

My suspicion would be there is a key in gsettings or dconf to set it, but I can't find one. Is there one, or is modifying `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf` the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, on Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop, unless you specifically override the configuration, the NTP server will be `ntp.ubuntu.com`. To check the current NTP server in use, use the `timedatectl timesync-status` command.

To your specific question, as you suspected, editing `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf` will provide you a way to specify an NTP server (or servers, plural). For details on that configuration file, see https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/timesyncd.conf.5.html.

Finally, unless I misunderstand the intent of your question, there's nothing specific to running Gnome 3 regarding the configuration of an NTP server.

Comment: So what happens when you turn off the Automatic Date & Time switch in Gnome Settings? Does that just disable systemd-timesyncd?

Comment: I did some investigation on my own and can confirm: After flipping the switch off, `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd` shows the service is dead and disabled.